# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on a non-object error

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I am trying to edit/update my image upload but I am getting "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on a non-object" error. please help

**My controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
      $lnkupdate=Request::all();

    $links=Links::findorFail($id);
    $file = Input::file('image');
  $random_name = str_random(8);
  $destinationPath = 'albums/';
  $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $filename=$random_name.'_link_logo.'.$extension;
  $uploadSuccess = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
  ConsularGen::update(array(
    'name'=>Input::get('name'),
    'link' => Input::get('link'),
    'image' => $filename,
    ));
}
```

**View:**

```
{!!Form::model($links,['method'=>'PATCH','action'=>['LinksController@update',$links->id]])!!}
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="image">Select a logo</label>
         {!!Form::file('image')!!}
        </div>

<div class="form-goup">
{!!Form::label('name','Name')!!}
{!!Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>

    <div class="form-goup">
{!!Form::label('link','Link')!!}
{!!Form::text('link',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btnbtn-default">Add</button>
</div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::patch('admin/links/{id}/update','LinksController@update');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading files requires the html form to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. If you don't have this, the file will not be uploaded, `Input::file('image')` will return `null`, and you'll get the error you're seeing.

The Laravel Form builder will add this to your form if you tell it that it needs to handle files. Add `'files' => true` to your array in the form:

```
{!! Form::model($links, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'files' => true, 'action'=>['LinksController@update', $links->id]]) !!}
```

Once this is fixed, you'll also get this error if you don't actually select a file to be uploaded. You should wrap your file handing inside a check to `hasFile`. Something like:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $lnkupdate=Request::all();

    if (Input::hasFile('image')) {
        $links=Links::findorFail($id);
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $random_name = str_random(8);
        $destinationPath = 'albums/';
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename=$random_name.'_link_logo.'.$extension;
        $uploadSuccess = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        ConsularGen::update(array(
            'name'=>Input::get('name'),
            'link' => Input::get('link'),
            'image' => $filename,
        ));
    } else {
        echo 'no file uploaded. oops.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried your code and now I am getting "Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context" error

Comment: Thank you @patricus for your help ,also I was able to solve "Non-static method..." error by doing this:
 Links::where('id',$id)->update(array(
        'name' => Input::get('name'),
        'link' =>Input::get('link'),
        'image' => $filename,
        ));

Comment: @user3810794 I only wrapped your existing code in the `hasFile()` check; I didn't attempt to check for any additional issues. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has not uploaded successfully.
you are trying to run getClientOriginalExtension() on a null file thats's why you are getting this error